# How to automatically output strings in loops

Tags: java, string, loops

So I just have a quick little issue

```
 int pickmeup = 0;
        while (true)
        {
        pickmeup = scanner.nextInt();
        if (pickmeup == 1)
         {System.out.println ("you entered 1");}
        if(pickmeup == 2)
         {System.out.println ("you entered 2");}
        {
            break;
        }
    System.out.println ("Invalid code");
```

Now when I run this code it all works fine however in regards to the strings but it seems as though the loop doesn't work all that well when I enter '3', as it doesn't return the string 'Invalid code'.

If I were to get rid of the strings after both if statements, then it works perfectly fine.  What exactly am I doing wrong? Are there other ways to automatically have strings output?

Comment: This code doesn't compile because of mismatched `{`.

Comment: ((pickmeup == 1)  is this ur real code

Comment: Sorry, I closed the brackets on the strings, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @getlost I've edited it to reflect my actual code. I made last minute changes and changed it back and forgot to edit it correctly.

Comment: Then fix your code first. Second if `if(pickmeup == 2)` is currently inside of the first one, just like the line `System.out.println ("Invalid code");`.

Comment: @Tom I suppose I should use brackets to separate them? I can loop perfectly fine with as many condition as I want but once I use strings I run into issues as the loop does NOT work.

Comment: Is this the code you're currently using? I don't think you can loop there more than once, because the `break` statement is inside its only block, that is not related to any `if` statement. That means it will be executed every time. See Elliotts answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use a logical or `||` and an `else` like,

```
int pickmeup;
while (true) {
    pickmeup = scanner.nextInt();
    if (pickmeup == 1 || pickmeup == 2) {
        System.out.printf("you entered %d%n", pickmeup);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid code");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an `else if` chain like,

```
int pickmeup;
while (true) {
    pickmeup = scanner.nextInt();
    if (pickmeup == 1) {
        System.out.println("you entered 1");
    } else if (pickmeup == 2) {
        System.out.println("you entered 2");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid code");
    }
}
```

Comment: Its funny, I did try an or statement, but I had issues figuring out how to make the strings work for it.  This looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could start with firstly correcting your code, you can do that in eclipse Source-Format or by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

For your example, I corrected as much as I understood, currently it breaks only if else is reached. Break can be modified.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pickmeup = 0;
    while (true){
        pickmeup = scanner.nextInt();
        if (pickmeup == 1){
            System.out.println("one");
        }
        else if (pickmeup == 2){
            System.out.println("two");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid code");
            break;
        }
    }
```